# How to get Emacs use the Ubuntu login password for tramp

Tags: tramp, ubuntu, passwords

Ubuntu 16.04 Emacs 26.1 Emacs needs to open the file with root privileges. Here is my code:

```
    (secrets-delete-item "session" "Login")
(secrets-create-item "session" "Login" "myParol" :method "sudo" :host "iemuser" :user "iemuser")
;(secrets-show-secrets)
; session
; `-[-] Login
;    |-  password:   myParol
;    |-  host:       iemuser
;    |-  user:       iemuser
;    |-  method:     sudo
;    `-  xdg:schema: org.freedesktop.Secret.Generic
(setq auth-sources '("secrets:session"))
(find-file "/sudo::/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/gnus/auth-source.el.gz")
```

and again Emacs persistently requires a password: Password for `/sudo:root@iemuser`: How to get Emacs to take the password from my Ubuntu login.

---

*Addition details from the comments:*

- `iemuser@iemuser` is not a mistake:

  - The localhost is named `iemuser`
  - I am logged in to that host (and running Emacs on that host) as a user with that same name, `iemuser`
- In emacs I wish to programmatically open a root-owned file on this localhost for editing. i.e.: `/sudo::/path/to/file`

  - My goal is to not be prompted for a sudo password when this happens -- rather, I want emacs to handle the authentication
  - I am trying to use `auth-sources` and `secrets` to achieve this

Comment: I don't know about the "secrets" stuff, but "`Password for /sudo:root@iemuser`" indicates that you're not actually accessing the correct path. I strongly suspect you've tried to access `/sudo:iemuser:...` which means "log me in as username `root` on the host `iemuser`" (hence `root@iemuser` in the prompt). The correct syntax (which is common to tramp paths in general) is `/sudo:USER@HOST:` with the `sudo` method using `root@` as the default user when no username is given. The incorrect attempt may also have created a `C-h v tramp-default-proxies-alist` entry for the bad hostname.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in the code, I did not want to write the real names of the host, user and password. I need to substitute the password from the code, and not enter it manually in the minibuffer. I am trying to pass a parol with the Parol element to the desired password for the host user, but the tramp asks persistently. If I enter the password in the minibuffer, everything opens, and more in this emacs session, the tramp does not ask for the password for this host and user.

Comment: So based on your edits the hostname and the username are *both* `iemuser`?  Is the `iemuser` host also the localhost, or is it remote?

Comment: `(find-file "/sudo::/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/gnus/auth-source.el.gz")` ought to be accessing that path on localhost, not on the `iemuser` host (although if there's an unfortunate `tramp-default-proxies-alist` entry from a use of incorrect syntax it's *possible* for localhost paths to end up being proxied to a remote host, but that's very much dependent on the specific proxies which are defined).

Comment: If `iemuser` is a remote host rather than the localhost, I would expect you to be using a path something like `/ssh:YOU@iemuser|sudo:iemuser@iemuser:/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/gnus/auth-source.el.gz`.  (If you're in a position to change either the username or the hostname, I'd suggest doing so -- I think having both of them the same makes things rather less obvious for you if you're trying to debug connectivity issues!)

Comment: host, local The hostname and username are the same. Trying to figure out how to work with tramp.

Comment: (find-file "/sudo::/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/gnus/auth-source.el.gz") works, but emacs requires you to enter the password sudo, but I'm trying to substitute this password for the tramp avoid interactive input

Comment: When I use (find-file "/sudo:iemuser@iemuser:/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/gnus/auth-source.el.gz") the file is opened only for reading, the password is not asked

Comment: Remember `/sudo::` is shorthand for `/sudo:root@localhost:` -- or more accurately, the return value of `(system-name)` rather than "localhost" verbatim.  So authentication for that vs authentication for `iemuser@iemuser` would be expected to be totally different things, and you need to use whatever is actually appropriate.

Comment: Is the following true?  (1) The localhost is named `iemuser`; (2) You are logged in to that host (and running Emacs on that host) as a user with that same name, `iemuser`; (3) You are wanting to edit a root-owned file on localhost; (4) You want Emacs to handle the authentication for `/sudo::/path/to/file` to sudo to `root` on localhost, so that you are not prompted for a password.

Comment: Yes, so that sudo can get root rights on localhost, and so that the password is substituted from the code and not interactively. I want to understand it locally for a while, then I will train at the remote. The database stores keys, user names, file paths, ssl certificates, and you want emacs to pick up this data from the code and not from my notebook interactively

Comment: In the previous comment you wrote it is necessary to literally indicate the username and host, if I understood you correctly, in my example, to record with the "Login" label of the "session" collection specify instead of the real username "iemuser" specify "root" that is, instead of "(secrets-create-item" session "" Login "" myParol ": method" sudo ": user" iemuuser ": host" iemuser ")" use "(secrets-create-item" session "" Login "" myParol " : method "sudo": user "root": host "iemuser") "with user password" iemuser "

Comment: I would like to help, but a discussion in the comments section doesn't look appropriate. Pls send your problem to the Tramp mailing list `tramp-devel@gnu.org`. Michael, Tramp maintainer.

Comment: Knowing how to do this is not very convenient with comments, it does not stand out for exactly which comment you keep the answer

Comment: I've updated the question with the clarifications as I understand them.  I recommend that you follow up with Michael as suggested.  Assuming that you work out a solution, please post the answer below so that others can benefit from it.  Note that you can (and probably should) 'Accept' your own answer in that situation.